# Access a view variable before it is declared

Tags: angular

My form validation works off the ng classes and in some cases I want to copy the classes up one level to the parent container.

```
<div [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid': input.invalid, 'ng-valid': input.valid, 'ng-pristine': input.pristine}">
  <input [name]="control.id" [(ngModel)]="control.value" required #input="ngModel">
</div>
```

This works for the most part, but I am getting the following error on the console:

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.

Is there a way I can reference a view variable before it is defined?

Comment: I think this is more the issue that you started something that changed a certain variable and then in the onslaught of that event, it changed again.

Comment: If I put the  [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid': input.invalid, 'ng-valid': input.valid, 'ng-pristine': input.pristine}" on an element after the input it doesn't throw any errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't certain that a certain variable will be defined you can use the Elvis operator.

```
<div [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid': input?.invalid, 'ng-valid': input?.valid, 'ng-pristine': input?.pristine}">
  <input [name]="control.id" [(ngModel)]="control.value" required #input="ngModel">
</div>
```

Perhaps you could create a new component that encapsulates the ngClass and the input? The input.xxx make it look like you should be using FormControls: they do the valid/invalid/pristine stuff for you..